# If properly regularized is a population of 8 individuals be enough to start a population

Tags: biology, humans

I am planning on writing a story/book and the idea I've got comes from other books I've read that start with
a similar premise, never take where I'm thinking. I was wondering if it was possible to have lets say about seven women and one man, isolated from anyone else start a viable population that will last. If possible how would they go about doing that.

If you want bonus points from me the other idea I had for this group was an outside force that causes there to be an only 1/4s chance of conceiving a male child.

Comment: This has already been extensively researched.  Try googling "minimum viable population humans".

Comment: Sure. IF they have access to a huge store of banked sperm and eggs from other people. Otherwise, no chance whatsoever.